# unable to implement if else condition on click event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set if condition on click event, there two portion in click event. One for checking textbox is blank yet or not and other on is to post via ajax. I just need to use `if condition` that work like, while text is blank ajax will not post anything and if not then ajax post. Please help me to get it done.

```
$("#attnUpdate").click(function (e) {
  //check textbox is blank                  
  $('.TID').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val() == ""){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.remarks').attr('placeholder','Input can not be left blank');
      alert('Input can not be left blank');
    }
  });
  //ajax post                 
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/statusUpdate",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#attnData").serialize() + '&fromAjax=' + true,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("Fail")
    }
  });
  e.preventDefault(); // could also use: return false;
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/erbbttf7/1/

Comment: sir, I do the same but still alert the first msg though I fill the selected text

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abzalali/4fomyjq5/

Comment: use `$(this).closest('tr').find('.remarks').val() == ""`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u93kp2pe/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not stopping when the error is there.

```
$('.TID').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val() == ""){
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.remarks').attr('placeholder','Input can not be left blank');
    alert('Input can not be left blank');
    // stop the execution.
    return false;
  }
});
```

Also, you can set a `flag` to check if there are errors and then fire the AJAX request.

```
$("#attnUpdate").click(function (e) {
  // set a flag
  error = false;
  //check textbox is blank
  $('.TID').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val() == ""){
      $(this).closest('tr').find('.remarks').attr('placeholder','Input can not be left blank');
      alert('Input can not be left blank');
      // set the error flag so that ajax won't fire.
      error = true;
    }
  });
  //ajax post
  if (!error)
    $.ajax({
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/attendance/statusUpdate",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#attnData").serialize() + '&fromAjax=' + true,
      success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Fail")
      }
    });
  e.preventDefault(); // could also use: return false;
});
```

Comment: You are just retunring from the each handler

Comment: @ArunPJohny Something to stop. Okay, I am gonna add another snippet using flag.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have updated the post by using a flag.

Comment: I set `if (!error)` before ajax and fill text although show the alert msg `Input can not be left blank`

Comment: @MirAbzalAli I don't understand. What is the issue now? Doesn't it work?

Comment: please take look on the link sir, still not working https://jsfiddle.net/abzalali/4fomyjq5/

Comment: @MirAbzalAli Sure. Lemme take a look.

Comment: @MirAbzalAli Add your HTML here, clone it and send me the link please: **http://jsbin.com/neyoyabufi/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: sir, here's the link but unable to view cause php code here also- http://jsbin.com/koxugotiga/1/edit?html,js

Comment: @MirAbzalAli JSBin or JSFiddle works only with HTML. So kindly put your generated HTML.

Comment: could you help me that how do I get generated HTML?

Comment: @MirAbzalAli Just copy and paste the contents from the browser's view source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102217/discussion-between-mir-abzal-ali-and-praveen-kumar).